# Outlook VBA code only works on one computer

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

So, this is one of perhaps the strangest issues I've had so far with VBA.

I've worked on a macro that does the following:

1. In the current email, it checks for a single XLS file.
2. If found, saves the attachment in a temporary folder, in order to read through the file.
3. Copy/Pastes a certain region into the body of the E-mail.
4. Uses Certain fields IN the email to auto-populate the subject line

So, I've got all of that to work on the computer I developed it on. Works fine, no problems. My boss tried to add it to his computer and it doesn't work. It gives this error

```
Run Time error -382271456(e9370020)
Cannot save the attachment
```

Below is the code, sorry for the read, I know it is a lot.

```
Sub Parse_Excel()
    Dim NewMail As MailItem, oInspector As Inspector
    Set oInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
    Dim eAttachment As Object, i As Integer, lRow As Integer, lCol As Integer, rng As Range, subject As String
    Dim codes As String, c As Variant, dArea As Range, dType As Range, dSev As Range, result As String, damage As String
    Dim lCommentRowRng As Range

    '~~> Get the current open item
    Set NewMail = oInspector.CurrentItem

    Set eAttachment = Excel.Application

    With NewMail.Attachments
        For i = 1 To .Count

            If InStr(.Item(i).FileName, ".xls") > 0 Then

                sFileName = Environ$("temp") & "/" & .Item(i).FileName
                ' Creates a temporary file in the temp folders for Outlook

                Debug.Print sFileName
                'Used to test something

                .Item(i).SaveAsFile sFileName
                ' Save file there

                eAttachment.Workbooks.Open sFileName
                'Open the saved file - this is necessary as you can't simply open it from outlook

                With eAttachment.Workbooks(.Item(i).FileName).Sheets(1)

                    Set lCommentRowRng = .Cells.Find("Comments")

                    Set rng = lCommentRowRng.Offset(0, 1)
                    ' Sometimes the comments will be on the bottom, so we need to have this to figure out how far down exactly the comment box goes
                    If Not lCommentRowRng.Row = (rng.Row + rng.MergeArea.Rows.Count) Then
                        lCommentRow = rng.Row + rng.MergeArea.Rows.Count
                        lCol = rng.Column + rng.MergeArea.Columns.Count - 1
                    Else
                        lCommentRow = lCommentRowRng.Row
                    End If
                    lPriorRow = .Cells.Find("Prior Inspections").Row
                    lRow = eAttachment.Max(lCommentRow, lPriorRow)
                    'The date of the report
                    Set rng = .Cells.Find("Date")
                    ddate = .Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + rng.MergeArea.Columns.Count).Value

                    'The VIN we are using
                    result = ""
                    With .Cells
                        Set c = .Find("VIN", LookIn:=xlValues)
                        If Not c Is Nothing Then
                            firstAddress = c.Address
                            Do

                                result = result & " " & Right(c.Offset(0, 1).Value, 8)

                                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
                        End If
                    End With
                    vin = result

                    'Make/Model
                    result = ""
                    With .Cells
                        Set c = .Find("Model", LookIn:=xlValues)
                        If Not c Is Nothing Then
                            firstAddress = c.Address
                            Do

                                If uInStr(result, c.Offset(0, 1).Value) = -1 Then
                                    result = result & " " & c.Offset(0, 1).Value
                                End If

                                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
                        End If
                    End With
                    model = result

                    Set rng = .Cells.Find("Origin")
                    ' Not all reports have Origin/Railcar Number fields, thus the If statements
                    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                        origin = .Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + rng.MergeArea.Columns.Count).Value
                    End If

                    Set rng = .Cells.Find("Railcar Number")
                    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                        Railcar = .Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + rng.MergeArea.Columns.Count).Value
                    End If

                    'Not all Reports have "Bay" Information
                    Set rng = .Cells.Find("Bay Location")
                    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                        bay = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    End If


                    result = ""
                    'The result variable, that will hold the string for the top
                    With .Cells
                        Set c = .Find("Damage Code", LookIn:=xlValues)
                        If Not c Is Nothing Then
                            firstAddress = c.Address
                            Do

                                Set dArea = c.Offset(0, 1)
                                Set dType = dArea.Offset(0, 1)
                                Set dSev = dType.Offset(0, 1)
                                ' It got really tricky trying to just use the c.offset thing since the columns are all merged - This works better.

                                damage = Left(dArea.Value, 2)
                                damage = damage & "." & Left(dType.Value, 2)
                                damage = damage & "." & dSev.Value & " "


                                If uInStr(result, damage) = -1 Then
                                    ' If the damage is not found within the string already, include it, otherwise just continue through the loop
                                    result = result & " " & damage
                                End If

                                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                                ' Get the next value
                            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
                        End If
                    End With

                    Set rng = .Range("A1", .Cells(lRow, lCol))

                    With NewMail

                        subject = .subject
                        subject = Replace(subject, "00/00/00", ddate)
                        subject = Replace(subject, "VIN# ", "VIN# " & vin)
                        subject = Replace(subject, "Make Model", model)
                        subject = Replace(subject, "ORIGIN", UCase(origin) & " ORIGIN")
                        subject = Replace(subject, "TTGXxxxx", Railcar)
                        subject = Replace(subject, "CODE: ", "CODE: " & result)
                        subject = Replace(subject, "CODES: ", "CODES: " & result)
                        subject = Replace(subject, "BAY#", "BAY# " & bay)
                        subject = Replace(subject, "  ", " ")
                        .subject = subject
                        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
                        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
                        .Display

                    End With

                End With


                eAttachment.Workbooks(.Item(i).FileName).Close

                Exit For

            End If

        Next
    End With

End Sub
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' By Ron de Bruin.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As workBook

    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    Set excelApp = New Excel.Application

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"


    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8        ' Paste over column widths from the file
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .Cells(1).Select
        excelApp.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         FileName:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
Function uInStr(haystack As String, needle As String) As Integer
    Dim nStr As Integer

    If haystack = "" Then
        ' Kept getting an error because I was trying to use the Left function an a string with no length
        uInStr = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    nStr = InStr(haystack, needle)
    If haystack = needle Then
        uInStr = 0
        Exit Function
    End If
    If nStr > 0 Then
        uInStr = nStr
        Exit Function
    Else

        If Not Left(haystack, Len(needle)) = needle Then
            uInStr = -1
            Exit Function
        Else
            uInStr = 0
            Exit Function
        End If

    End If
End Function
```

**EDIT:** In order to get it to work, I simply had to change the directory that the file was being saved in. For some reason my boss' computer didn't have access to the environment path (which was weird on its own). So now the code reads:

```
sFileName =   "C:/temp/" & .Item(i).FileName
... Other Code here
Kill "C:/temp/*.xls"
```

Thanks for the help everybody.

Comment: Not sure why are you using `/` instead of `\`. Are you sure your boss has access to `sFileName` path?

Comment: It's a temporary folder, so I would imagine? I would check but I can't access that location directly, because it's a temporary folder.

Comment: To add further confusion, my boss says that if he has 2 instances of the email template we use open, and he attaches the same file to both, it will work on the second one, but not the first.

Comment: try to use something like c:\temp\ instead of Environ$("temp")

Comment: I'll try that when I get to the office. That was what I originally had done previously, but i had gotten some help on the RangetoHTML function and preferred that to a simple "c:/temp/"

Comment: If you put your edit in an answer and accept it, searchers from the future will know there is an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had edited this, and just so we are clear, what ended up happening is that my boss' computer didn't have access to the environment variable for some weird reason. The code now reads :

```
sFileName =   "C:/temp/" & .Item(i).FileName
... Other Code here
Kill "C:/temp/*.xls"
```